# What does the tilde character (~) do in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, tilde

What effect does the tilde character `~` have in math mode?  Is it the same non-breaking space that it is in text mode?  Is it bad style to use `~` in math mode?  I've seen it used in some examples but have not seen it explained in any of the usual LaTeX references.

Answer (score 24):

Using `~` or `\⍽` (control space, just in order to make it clear) in math mode is not equivalent, as the following example shows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

$a=\ =b$

$a=~=b$

\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

Why is that? Because the definition of `~` is

```
1299 \DeclareRobustCommand{\nobreakspace}{%
1300    \leavevmode\nobreak\ }
1301 \catcode `\~=13
1302 \def~{\nobreakspace{}}
```

(line numbers are those in `latex.ltx`). Thus `~` also adds a `{}` group that's significant in math mode and explains the difference in output: in the first line we have (**Ord** stands for an atom of class “ordinary”, **Rel** for an atom of class “binary relation”)

> **Ord** **Rel** `<skip>` **Rel** **Ord**

and TeX ignores explicit skips when deciding what math spacing to insert. So by rule it inserts a thick space between **Ord** and **Rel** and between **Rel** and **Ord**, but no space between **Rel** and **Rel**. The `<skip>` due to `\⍽` is inserted back when converting the math list to a horizontal box.

In the second case we have

> **Ord** **Rel** `<skip>` **Ord** **Rel** **Ord**

because in math mode `{}` counts as an **Ord** atom. Thick spaces will be inserted at either side of the empty **Ord** atom.

Thus it's better to use `\⍽` instead of `~`, in order to avoid surprises. However, the usage should be limited to separating parts of a formula that need to be considered as words, typically in displays. There's no difference between

```
\[
\sin\pi = 0\ \text{and}\ \cos\pi = -1
\]
```

and

```
\[
\sin\pi = 0 \text{ and } \cos\pi = -1
\]
```

Just a question of personal preference, because either will use the interword space relative to the current font outside of math, without stretching or shrinking. For spacing math symbols the best is to use `\mkern` or `\mskip` (possibly the latter, for which `amsmath` provides the `\mspace` interface, analog to `\hspace`).

Note that in inline math mode `\⍽\text{and}\⍽` and `\text{⍽and⍽}` are different, as the former inserts spaces that may participate to stretching and shrinking, whereas the latter inserts “frozen” spaces. However, something like

```
the set $N_n(R)=\{\,x\in R: x^{n-1}\ne 0\ \text{and}\ x^{n}=0\,\}$
```

is more properly written as

```
the set $N_n(R)=\{\,x\in R: x^{n-1}\ne 0$ and~$x^{n}=0\,\}$
```

so as to give TeX more chances to properly break the line.

Comment: sigh. I  missed the `{}` I suppose I'll have to delete mine now.

Comment: Why LaTeX includes this `{}` in the code of `~`? This seems as absurd from first point of view.

Comment: @wipet I don't know; there's no explanation for it in `source2e.pdf`.

Comment: @wipet If something like `abc~ def` gets into a moving argument, it will be written out as `abc\protect \nobreakspace  {} def`. Without the `{}` the space before `def` would be ignored. Reaction to bug due to bad coding.

Comment: OK, I (independently) found out the same. But still, it seems to me as absurd.

Comment: @wipet Well I guess today the decision would be different as you'd use `\protected\def` and the moving argument situation would not be there.

Comment: @egreg `\ \text{and}\ ` _versus_ `\text{ and }` is of course potentially different if not in display math (_cf._ work I'm currently doing in `siunitx`).

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, of course, but using `\text{ and }` in text mode is not recommendable: better exiting from math mode and reentering it, if really needed.

Comment: @egreg yes, I was thinking from a more programming POV where you might not know what the surrounds are up to, and where there isn't a safe way to _leave_ math mode without using a box.

Comment: Very very useful information! However I am slightly scared by the last example...I see the TeXnical point but it seems "wrong" semantically...is there really no better way?

Comment: @egreg ...the style of last example can also lead to errors, for example:
`$\left\{\frac{A}{B}: A>0$ and $B<9 \right\}$`
as opposed to
`$\left\{\frac{A}{B}: A>0 \text{ and } B<9 \right\}$` which however cannot be broken...

Comment: @Bordaigorl If one uses correctly `\left` and `\right`, the problem wouldn't even appear. There's no justification for `\left` and `\right` in your code.

Comment: @egreg ok, my example was artificial, just to illustrate the issue...I am just asking since `$ $` couples are conceptually like parenthesis and the last example of your answer is not well-parenthesised...