# what does tilde `~` do specifically?

Tags: symbols, characters

I was thinking about the reserved character in $\LaTeX$, but I don't know the real function of `~` neither I've use it before. Then, what is its real function in general.

For `math mode` I found this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203686/what-does-the-tilde-character-do-in-math-mode). But in `text mode`?

Comment: @hkviktor Well, it's got an answer now. I'll check other people's opinion, and it may get closed as a duplicate (I hope you wouldn't really mind!). However, you shouldn't delete it I think.